# VBA type mismatch error in QueryTables

Tags: vba

I'm getting a type mismatch range error at line 8. Can anyone please so kindly explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set objSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add(1)

With objExcel.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection="TEXT;C:\temp\file.csv", Destination=Range("$A$1"))
    '.CommandType = 0
    .Name = "test_ITS_ExtractX"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 850
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery=False
End With

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename="c:/temp/file.xlsx", FileFormat=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup=False
```

objExcel.DisplayAlerts = True
objExcel.Quit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your code actually is written in one of the VBA variants, the named parameters should be specified using `:=` instead of just `=`.  This generates a "Type mismatch" error when I run your code.

You also have an unqualified `Range` object (see [answer by Domenic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45852659/6535336)), which will cause problems once you correct the syntax errors.

So the correct line should be:

```
With objExcel.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\temp\file.csv", _
                                          Destination:=objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1"))
```

and one of your later lines should be

```
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="c:\temp\file.xlsx", _
                               FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, _
                               CreateBackup:=False
```

and I just noticed

```
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

(Note: Please ensure that the `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` constant is available in whichever application you are running this in.  If not, you will need to assign the correct value to it yourself.  The same will apply for `xlInsertDeleteCells`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer and additional info, it certainly helps with my very limited vba knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
With objExcel.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\temp\file.csv", Destination:=objExcel.ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. Helps a lot!

Comment: I've edited my post as per `YowE3K`'s remarks regarding named parameters.